# Why is the resulting file unplayable when I use FFMPEG to convert a MP4 video to ASF?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I want to convert an .mp4 file to an .asf file, but I need to keep the size of the file below 150 mb (the server I need to upload the file to can only take files under 150 mb). Basically I want to recontain the .mp4 in an .asf file. The code I'm using currently is

ffmpeg input.mp4 -c copy output.asf

The command runs, however when I try to play the file on windows media player (I'm on windows xp) I get an error message saying "Windows media player has encountered a problem while playing the file."

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? And what other ways I can accomplish this task?

Comment: Are you able to play the file back on another program (e.g. VLC, Media Player Classic)?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the full, uncut console output that you get from `ffmpeg`. Usually, H.264 video is not entirely supported in ASF streams. Can you only upload ASF files? Where are you uploading to? Please [edit] your question with more info. Thank you.